# Is there any npm package or any solution to access file from weblogic server

Tags: reactjs, weblogic

I am looking to access a file from weblogic server. Can anyone suggest me solution for this, It could be a npm package or any other way.

Previously I used express for Node.js and aws npm for cloud. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your needs. What do you mean by "to access a file from weblogic server"
WebLogic Server is a java application server.

Comment: there is a json file in server location. i want to read the contents inside that and use them in my code in react apllication.

Comment: This json file should be readable from an URL (REST API or web app for instance)